# Iphone: How to update a table view that displays managed objects when new object is added

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data

I have a table view that displays managed objects (Tasks).
I'd like to fetch all tasks and update the table view once a task is added or modified.

Currently refresh the tasks array when NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification is fired.
But I'm afraid that this could be quite inefficient as the table is also updated when other objects are modified.

Is there any way to update my table view only when the Tasks relation is changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found the answer for my question:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html